# Python - if class eventListener syntax tree

Tags: python, sublimetext

I'm new to Python(3.3), and currently develop SublimeText(3) plugin.

I want my plugin behave only for a specific file type; say `*.txt`.

So far I have a code like below:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, socket

class MarkdownLiveCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self,view):  
        do-things

class MyEventListener1(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified_async(self,view):
        do-things

class MyEventListener2(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load_async(self,view):
        do-things
```

So, I tried

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, socket

if False:

    class MarkdownLiveCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self,view):  
            do-things

    class MyEventListener1(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
        def on_modified_async(self,view):
            do-things

    class MyEventListener2(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
        def on_load_async(self,view):
            do-things
```

the eventLisners keep working even if False;

Actually, I don't know how `class` behaves in the syntax tree, so please let me know
which manner is right to achieve my purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you change `if False:` to `while False:`?

Comment: Nothing @MattDmo , while False triggers the following events class